# Gulp complaining about directory already existing when running clean & deploy tasks

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have the following gulp tasks setup in my project.  All was well until I added the `dist:images` tasks.

Now every other run when using the `dist:watch` task causes the error

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir '/Users/toby/src/my-project/dist/imgs'
```

I can see that the clean task is finishing before the others start.  I've also tested that no other task is creating that folder… so how come the `dist:images` task is creating this directory and then complaining about it!?!

Here's the code...

```
/**
 * dist:clean
 */
gulp.task('dist:clean', function () {
    del(config.distDir + "/**/*");
});

gulp.task('dist:html', ['dist:clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.htmlFiles)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist:images', ['dist:clean'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.imgFiles, {base: "web"})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist:styles', ['dist:clean'], function () {
    console.log(config.lessMainFile);
    return gulp.src(config.lessMainFile)
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(less().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir + "/css"));
});

gulp.task('dist:src', ['dist:clean', 'src']);

/**
 * dist:browserify
 */
gulp.task("dist:browserify", ['dist:src'], function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir     : '.',
        debug       : true,
        entries     : [config.buildJsDir + '/src/main.js'],
        cache       : {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('js/main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist', ['dist:html', 'dist:images', 'dist:styles', 'dist:src', 'dist:browserify']);


gulp.task('dist:watch', ['dist'], function () {
    return gulp.watch(config.srcAllTypeScript.concat(config.webDir + "/**/*"), ['dist']);
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Try `return del(config.distDir + "/**/*")` or `del.sync(config.distDir + "/**/*")` in your `dist:clean` task.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is quite related to gulp and watch tasks.
You are deleting the `config.imgFiles` directory every time a file changes in every task, and you are also creating the folder every time a file changes, thus you end up in a OS system race condition.

This has the `dist:clean` task used only on the initial start of the build.

```
/**
 * dist:clean
 */
gulp.task('dist:clean', function () {
    del(config.distDir + "/**/*");
});

gulp.task('dist:html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.htmlFiles)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist:images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.imgFiles, {base: "web"})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist:styles', function () {
    console.log(config.lessMainFile);
    return gulp.src(config.lessMainFile)
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(less().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }))
        .pipe(cssmin().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir + "/css"));
});

gulp.task('dist:src', function() {
  // I did not see any `dist:src` task, so I added a placeholder
});

/**
 * dist:browserify
 */
gulp.task('dist:browserify', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir     : '.',
        debug       : true,
        entries     : [config.buildJsDir + '/src/main.js'],
        cache       : {},
        packageCache: {}
    })
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('js/main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.distDir));
});

gulp.task('dist', ['dist:html', 'dist:images', 'dist:styles', 'dist:src', 'dist:browserify']);


gulp.task('dist:watch', ['dist'], function () {
    return gulp.watch(config.srcAllTypeScript.concat(config.webDir + "/**/*"), ['dist']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['dist:clean', 'dist', 'dist:watch']);
```

Comment: This is worse than before. `['dist:clean', 'dist', 'dist:watch']` means you're running `dist:clean` and `dist` **concurrently**. It does **not** run `dist:clean` before `dist`. Read the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps).